# Read the commands from the text file and execute in sequence

Tags: c

So I am told to write a program in which program should read and execute a list of commands from `stdin`. Each command and its arguments (if any) will appear on a separate line. My program works to their needs but only if I write `./sequence text.file` or `./sequence < text.file text.file` in the terminal but it is supposed to work when I write `./sequence < text.file`.  I can't find the the bug in my code and moreover if someone can show me a better way of doing it will be really appreciated.

`text.file`

```
whoami
cal 4 2020
echo The time is:
date
```

CODE

```
#define MAX 10
#define LETTERS 256

/*Function definition to parse the command */
void parse(char *line, char **argv){


    char *token = line;
    char *extra;

  /* keep running until the end of the line  */

    while ((token = strtok_r(token, " \t\n", &extra)) != 0)
    {
        *argv++ = token;
        token = 0;
    }
  /* point the end of the argument to NULL*/

    *argv = 0;
}

/*Function definition of main()*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char *arg[MAX],line[LETTERS];

    FILE *fp;

   /* Error checking for file opening */

    fp = fopen( argv, "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("ERROR NO input file \n");
        return 0;
    }
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    /* Reading file line by line */

    while(fgets(line,LETTERS,fp)!= NULL){

        pid = fork();
    /*Errro checking for creation of child */

        if(pid < 0){
            printf("Fork child process failed!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(pid == 0){
            parse(line,arg);
            if(execvp(*arg,NULL) < 0){
                printf("Execvp failed!!\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else{
            wait(&status);       //Waiting for child process to finish.
        }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

TERMINAL

```
./sequence < text.file text.file
```

or

```
./sequence text.file
```

RESULT

```
manrajnsinghdua
     April 2020
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30

The time is:
Thu Apr 30 11:13:11 ACST 2020
```

Comment: may I suggest to wrap your entire program in $```$ (without $)? The two `#define` seems to be unnecessarily large...

Comment: @user12986714 there is a pending edit that fixes the formatting but it's not approved yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `fopen()` is not quite right, should be `fopen(argv[1], "r");`, but only after you confirm that `argc >= 2`

---

Instead of doing `fopen()`, it sounds like you just want to use `stdin`.

If you want to minimize your code changes, change:

```
    fp = fopen( argv, "r");
```

to

```
    fp = stdin;
```